# Why were some guns such as the Thompson submachine gun nicknamed 'chicago piano'?

Tags: etymology, slang, phrase-origin, nicknames

It's a 1920s gangster/mob thing, to keep your submachine gun in some kind of case resembling an instrument, so I can understand why they were called other nicknames like 'Chicago Typewriter' (typewriters came in such a case) but I am not sure why the word 'piano' applies.

I've done some googling and although many pages say it was a nickname, I can't really find any evidence as to why. Is it the shape? The sound? The way it looks?

I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: There is the point that the guns were supposedly often concealed in a violin case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *[OED](https://oed.com/)* (paywalled), 'Chicago piano' has provided a slang name for two guns:

> **a.** *(a)* *British Navy* an anti-aircraft gun on a ship;  *(b)* a Thompson sub-machine gun.

The subordinating entry, sense 3 of "Chicago, *n.*", suggests a rationale for the slang use of 'Chicago' more generally; *OED* also records pairing of 'Chicago' in this slang sense with **b.** 'overcoat' and **c.** 'typewriter'.

> **3.** *slang.* As a modifier, with euphemistic or humorous reference to the reputed violence and lawlessness of Chicago during the Prohibition era (1920–33). Now chiefly *historical.*

The overarching defining sense emphasizes the historical aspect of why 'Chicago' was paired with 'piano' as a nickname for the guns, as well as with 'overcoat' as a nickname for coffins, and again with 'typewriter' as a nickname for the Thompson submachine gun. The overall sense does not, however, afford us a specific explanation of why 'piano', or 'overcoat', or 'typewriter', would have been paired with 'Chicago' in the slang sense.

In the case of 'Chicago piano', one of the attestations given by *OED* does offer an anecdotal explanation for at least the use with reference to the Thompson:

> 1943   *Washington Post* 31 Oct. 2 b/7   You don't fire on this gun [*sc.* a tommy gun]... You play on it. That's why it's called the Chicago piano. You have to have rhythm.

The earlier British use of 'Chicago piano' in the sense of "an anti-aircraft gun on a ship", also called a 'pompom', attested from 1936,

> …the name sailors of the British Royal Navy have given their new multibarrelled antiaircraft guns, "Chicago pianos".
>
> *St. Louis Globe-Democrat*, St. Louis, Missouri, 09 May [1936](https://www.newspapers.com/image/573366349/?terms=%22chicago%20piano%22&match=1), p. 14 (paywalled).

may have contributed to later application of 'Chicago piano' to Thompson submachine guns, attested from 1941 (1943 in *OED*):

> It took three clips from the "Chicago piano" to mow Teddy [an elephant, *ed.*] down.
>
> *Daily News*, New York, 20 Oct [1941](https://www.newspapers.com/image/432793720/?terms=%22chicago%2Bpiano%22), p. 23 (paywalled).

Use of 'Chicago piano' in the sense of "multibarrelled antiaircraft gun", the pompom, continued for decades.

Evidence from 1938 shows a conceptual link between the pompom and the submachine gun:

> Only a week or two ago, the British Admiralty was proudly demonstrating to King George its new eight-barreled anti-aircraft guns, "Chicago pianos,"…named, forsooth, after the sawed-off shotguns and the "Tommy-guns" of Chicago's ex-gansters.
>
> *St. Louis Post-Dispatch*, Missouri, 08 Jul [1938](https://www.newspapers.com/image/138331579/?terms=%22chicago%20piano%22%20%22gangsters%22&match=1), p. 16 (paywalled).

Other than the historical "reference to the reputed violence and lawlessness of Chicago during the Prohibition era (1920–33)" (*OED*), an obvious reason the pompom was called the 'Chicago piano' was its appearance:

> [image: PomPom multibarrel anti-aircraft gun]
>
> *From Dam Neck to Okinawa*, Robert F. Wallace, [2001](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=msu.31293020930206&view=1up&seq=9&q1=%22chicago%20piano%22).

> [image: PomPom again]
>
> *He's in the sub-busters now*, A. D. Rathbone, [1943](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4522254&view=1up&seq=87&q1=%22chicago%20piano%22).

The sources I consulted also mentioned, as supposed reasons for the 'Chicago piano' nickname, a musical quality of the sound of both the pompom and the submachine gun, and a similarity between the sweeping action involved in firing the guns and the sweeping action involved in playing keyboard instruments.

Comment: While the pompom and the piano might keyboard techniques, the Thompson submachine gun has no keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Chicago](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/w4sdpfa#ph5wcjy) as an adjective has been used since the ‘20s in different contexts:

> used in combinations  especially  with reference to Chicago as a centre of 1920s–30s gangsterism.

***Chicago piano (n.)***

> a Thompson sub-machinegun, which achieved notoriety as the preferred weapon of Chicago gangsters in the 1920s and later.

> - c.1943  [US]    *‘Bill O. Lading’ You Chirped a Chinful!! n.p.: Chicago Piano: Tommy gun.*

> - 1946    [US]    Charleston (WV) Daily Mail 2 Sept. 6/5: *Me schmaltzy gabber couldn’t red a Chicago piano rap, so the D.A. conks me with a whole mag.*

(GDoS)

Comment: Do you have evidence from the 1920s?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

"Chicago piano" could be literal. Toy pianos, like Schroeder's from Peanuts, or a true "toy" like I've shown here may have been remarkably common.